# Nginx conf how to remove leading slash from $uri

Tags: nginx

My Nginx conf file :

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
  }

  ## PHP conf in case it's relevant 
  location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
```

Trying the following URL : `http://example.org/login` :

**expected behavior :**

`http://example.org/index.php?url=login`

**actual behavior :**

`http://example.org/index.php?url=/login`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a named location and an internal rewrite. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is the Nginx default behavior a good practice or standard of some kind? I would like to know if I should rewrite my app instead of my nginx conf.

Comment: You might rewrite your app to make the leading `/` optional. But `nginx` and Apache seem to have opposing policy when it comes to the leading `/` on URIs.

Comment: "But nginx and Apache seem to have opposing policy when it comes to the leading / on URIs." - The "difference in policy" on Apache is only with regards to the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ and only when used in a _directory_ (or `.htaccess`) context (which doesn't exist on Nginx). When used in a _server_ (or _virtualhost_) context then Apache is the same as Nginx in this respect. And then there is the Apache `REQUEST_URI` server variable, which always contains the full URL-path - the same as Nginx `$uri`.